# Get events from Google Calendar to show in FullCalendar for React.js

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have tried displaying a Google Calendar in my React project with FullCalendar by following their [events from  Google Calendar instructions](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) and got errors about unreachable code. Then I tried adapting it for React. The result was a nice calendar with no data.

Here is my code. As you can see, I am not using 'Calendar' like shown in the instructions but rather FullCalendar.

```
import React from "react";
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import {Calendar} from "@fullcalendar/core";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';

const GoogleCalendar = () => {
  return (      
    <FullCalendar
        plugins={[timeGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
        initialView="timeGridDay"
        googleCalendarApiKey= <MY_API_KEY>
        events={[
            { googleCalendarId: <MY_CALENDAR_ID> }
          ]}
      />
    );
};

export default GoogleCalendar;
```

- When I use **FullCalendar** I see a calendar on the page but it contains
  no data from Google Calendar despite there being test events in there. I get no console errors.
- When I use **Calendar** instead of FullCalendar, I see a blank page and
  get the following errors:

[image]

Can anyone help me? I have not had any luck getting a Google Calendar to display on a page!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few minutes ago. My solution is changing 'events' -> 'eventSources'.

Comment: can you explain more what is the difference please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your calendar public

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FullCalendar`, not `Calendar`. Also you have to enclose `events` like this:

```
events = {{ googleCalendarId: smthn }}
```